# HTML5 section or div for outer container

Tags: html

I need a container to contain all elements between the open body and closing body tag. 
My question is, should this container be a section or a div. I think section would be the wisest decision as it is a generic section of the document, but would like others opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "My question is, should this container be a section or a div."

In a short answer: Use a `<div>`.

Here is what the spec has to say about it:

> "The section element is **not a generic container** element. When an element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to **use the div element instead**."

If you want to read more on the specs here is the link:

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element